Need help with beetle identification and yellow stuff I am seeing
This beetle infested a kitchen in northeast USA.
enter image description here

Welcome Ken. Could you give us some idea of scale, also add any details about there in the house you found them (near wood, human food or maybe houseplants?). Were there any obvious traces of foodstuff, droppings or unusual dust? (Or even eggs?)

I can verify that this is a beetle - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle - the hard, wing cases are diagnostic - but until you provide more details about them I can't be any more specific.

Thanks @JiminyCricket. And Sir thinkalot.. I added more pics. Does that help identify? Although I can’t rule old boxed human food, I think they were attracted to or came from dog food and dog treats that were not sealed properly. Found ants in some dog food. Are attracted to light in kitchen and in general. Tiny ones sometime land on my cell phone screen at night. Also see dead ones around terrace door. All food now thrown out or in plastic containers.

I thought drugstore beetle but looks like furniture beetle to me. Thought about hyde beetle too. Can someone assist me? Thanks

@JiminyCricket. just trying to tag jiminycricket. Thanks

Hi. You've gotten my upvote - excellent pictures BTW. Before an answer appears, I am delighted to state with some certainty it's a beetle, but it's not a death-watch beetle.

@SirThinksalot. Thanks Jiminy. Trying to tag Sirthinksalot now.

We've this marvelous button the network developers put in, the follow facility. When activated, anyone interested automatically gets a ping when a comment/answer/edit happens. He probably knows.

Ok. Thanks @JiminyCricket.o thought drugstore beetle but someone else thought cigarette beetle.jfoakes Pheromone trap for pantry moths and “ beetle ( cigarette but not drugstore beetle I’m told) didn’t work.

My suspicion is furniture beetle (almost newly-formed adults), but I should wait for the experts, there are many related species and similar ones that aren't related at all.

For what it's worth, the two pictures of plastic (container?) don't contain any insect as far as I can tell.

@bob1 you may be right. I thought the white stuff may have been a nest. I vaccumed it so can’t get any more photos.

Also seeing brown stuff, I thought was dog food but now don’t think it is. Found something living in it. Photos attached. Any help would be appreciated.

Anybody out there? At very least I have merchant and cigarette beetles. Do they leave all this yellow stuff or do I have wood eating too?

I'm not sure who the entomologists here are, but there's quite a few members that pop-in on weekends and at odd times rather than every day. Just a thought, because tags act to ping people in some way or other on their feeds, it might be worth adding the [beetle] tag maybe the [insect] (or [insecta]) one too, if they exist.

@JiminyCricket. Not sure how to add a tag. To the title? Thanks

@JiminyCricket.sorry, how do I tag an existing post?

Click the [edit] button under the question (or the link in this comment) then look beneath the edit window, you'll see a horizontal box labeled "tags",  select it, just start typing - if the tag exists it should give you a drop-down of available tags that start with those letters.

@JiminyCricket.Thanks. Only insect is set up as a tag. Added it.thanks

Posted another pic. My question is whether the yellow stuff is consistent with Merchant and/or cigarette beetles or is this wood.

@JiminyCricket know of any other sites I can post my question? Thanks

I can't say I've used them myself, but there are several: Whatsthatbug and insectidentification seem to be up at present, not to mention there's almost certainly a Reddit thread or two out there.
